# Java String hascode preserving order and Hash based partitioning

Tags: java, hadoop, partitioning

Based on following function from java api doc it does seem to preserve order. 
`s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`
I also tested out with some examples that hascode are in similar order as actual strings. But just wanted to check with others in case I am missing something here.

My subsequent question is regarding whether to use HashPartitioner or OrderPreservingPartitioner in big data application using hadoop or spark. if your key is just a Java String then HashPartitioner should preserve order as well, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is wrong: it doesn't preserve order.
`"Aa"` has a `hashCode` of `2112`, `BA` has a `hashCode` of `2111`.  `"Aa"` comes before `"BA"` but its `hashCode` is bigger.

(Additionally, it doesn't take very long strings before you overflow ints and the numbers start wrapping around, which would also violate your assumption.)

So no, none of these preserve order.

Comment: Thanks. Yes in another example I tried where it overflowed ints and hashcode came out negative and violated order.